# How to change the colour of the lines representing range of variables in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe called `cpp` (in the Rdata file provided in the link below). I want to set the colour in my plot for the range of values listed below. I tried with my code below, but for some reason it is not separating the line colour as expected.If you look at the `p2` plot, the colour legend is not in congruent with the colour of the lines and the `cutoff` column. Can someone please help me.

Rdata file:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43417085/mydata.RData

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#setting colour for the range of values
    cpp$cutoff <- NA
    cpp$cutoff["A" <- cpp$mybs <= -0.1] <- "forestgreen" 
    cpp$cutoff["B" <- cpp$mybs > -0.1 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.1] <- "yellow1" 
    cpp$cutoff["C" <- cpp$mybs > 0.1 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.22] <- "slateblue2" 
    cpp$cutoff["D" <- cpp$mybs > 0.22 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.27] <- "navy" 
    cpp$cutoff["E" <- cpp$mybs > 0.27 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.46] <- "black" 
    cpp$cutoff["F" <- cpp$mybs > 0.46 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.56] <- "navy" 
    cpp$cutoff["G" <- cpp$mybs > 0.56 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.9] <- "red2" 
    cpp$cutoff["H" <- cpp$mybs > 0.9 &  cpp$mybs<= 1.25] <- "navy" 
    cpp$cutoff["I" <- cpp$mybs > 1.25] <- "red2" 

    ##plotting here
    p<- ggplot(cpp, aes(x = my_good, y = mybs, group = key, color = cutoff)) +
      geom_line() + geom_point()  #to show the dots


      p1 <- p+labs(title="Threshold", x="Number wanted", y="mybs") +

      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14), axis.title.x=element_text(size=16),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=14), axis.title.x=element_text(size=16),
            plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold", color="darkgreen"))

    p2 <-p1+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 1500, seq(5000, max(as.data.frame(cpp[,"my_good"])), 10000)),
                         labels = c(0, 1500, seq(5000, max(as.data.frame(cpp[,"my_good"])),10000)))  #expand forces the origin to start at zero

    p  #original plot
```

Comment: How does your expected plot look like?

Comment: @kitman0804 Expected plot should have the color range as set in `cpp$cutoff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the color name in the aestetics, `aes()`, directly.
Instead, pass a character vector (e.g. `color`) to `scale_color_manual()` (see the documentation [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_manual.html)).

I have replaced the names of the colors in the `cutoff` column by just letters, although you could also keep the color names, if you named your `color` character vector accordingly.

This should give the desired [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onexO.png):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#setting colour for the range of values
cpp$cutoff <- NA
cpp$cutoff["A" <- cpp$mybs <= -0.1] <- "A" 
cpp$cutoff["B" <- cpp$mybs > -0.1 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.1] <- "B" 
cpp$cutoff["C" <- cpp$mybs > 0.1 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.22] <- "C" 
cpp$cutoff["D" <- cpp$mybs > 0.22 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.27] <- "D" 
cpp$cutoff["E" <- cpp$mybs > 0.27 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.46] <- "E" 
cpp$cutoff["F" <- cpp$mybs > 0.46 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.56] <- "F" 
cpp$cutoff["G" <- cpp$mybs > 0.56 &  cpp$mybs<= 0.9] <- "G" 
cpp$cutoff["H" <- cpp$mybs > 0.9 &  cpp$mybs<= 1.25] <- "H" 
cpp$cutoff["I" <- cpp$mybs > 1.25] <- "I" 

##plotting here
p<- ggplot(cpp, aes(x = my_good, y = mybs, group = key, color = cutoff)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point()  #to show the dots


p1 <- p+labs(title="Threshold", x="Number wanted", y="mybs") +

  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14), axis.title.x=element_text(size=16),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14), axis.title.x=element_text(size=16),
        plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold", color="darkgreen"))

p2 <-p1+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 1500, seq(5000, max(as.data.frame(cpp[,"my_good"])), 10000)),
                            labels = c(0, 1500, seq(5000, max(as.data.frame(cpp[,"my_good"])),10000)))  #expand forces the origin to start at zero

# construct the named character vector to pass to scale_color_manual
color <- c("A" = "forestgreen", 
           "B" = "yellow1", "C" = "slateblue2", 
           "D" = "navy", "E" = "black", 
           "F" = "navy" , "G" = "red2", 
           "H" = "navy" , "I" = "red2")

# plot p1 with the colors defined
p1 + scale_color_manual(values = color)
```